# Cocoapod ставит старую версию библиотеки

Tags: ios, pod

если прописать в podfile: pod 'OneSignal', то ставится старая версия 1.13.0;
если явно указать желаемую версию: pod 'OneSignal', '~> 2.3', то не может установить такую - см. скрин. ниже:

[image]

если зайти в podspec, то видно, что последняя версия OneSignal: 2.3.5, но если сделать pod search onesignal в терминале, то он находит только версию 1.13.0 - см. скрин ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

pod --version = 1.0.1

Подскажите, что не так делаю, что вместо 2.3.5 получаю 1.13.0 (остальные библиотеки из pod-файла ставятся корректно)? И что надо сделать чтобы поставилась 2.3.5?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй обновить CocoaPods, на сайте указано что минимальная версия 1.1[image: туториал от OneSignal]

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но у меня похоже что-то именно с самим cocoapods на этом компе (еще не разобрался что конкретно). На нем и cocopods версии 1.1.1 ставит первую версию onesigal при pod install (при pod update выдает ошибку). В тоже время на другом компьютере cocoapods 1.0.1 нормально ставит onesignal требуемой версии для этого проекта ..